# How can I repeat this animation in CSS?

Tags: css, animation

I have this sample:

[link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rwMzNK)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="quote">
              <a id="dex-sign" class="play" href="http://drygiel.com" target="_blank"></a>
      </div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
#dex-sign {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px 10px 15px 10px;
    width: 255px;
    height: 84px;
    background: url(http://drygiel.com/projects/sign/frames.png) no-repeat;
}

#dex-sign.play {
    -moz-animation: sign-anim 3.5s 0.2s steps(85) forwards;
    -o-animation: sign-anim 3.5s 0.2s steps(85) forwards;
    -webkit-animation: sign-anim 3.5s 0.2s steps(85) forwards;
    animation: sign-anim 3.5s 0.2s steps(85) forwards;
}
a#dex-sign {
    opacity: .9;
}
a#dex-sign:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-filter: invert(30%) brightness(80%) sepia(100%) contrast(110%) saturate(953%) hue-rotate(165deg);
}
@-webkit-keyframes sign-anim {
    to {
        background-position: 0 -7140px;
    }
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes sign-anim {
    to {
        background-position: 0 -7140px;
    }
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes sign-anim {
    to {
        background-position: 0 -7140px;
    }
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

I tried to add `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` But it still does not work.
With Jquery is simple but I would not use it.

Can you please tell me what I should do?Do I have to add something else to work?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: `animation: sign-anim 3.5s 0.2s steps(85) forwards infinite;`

Comment: you can also alternate :`animation: sign-anim 3.5s 0.2s steps(85) forwards infinite alternate;` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VWKzKw

Comment: You've placed `animation-iteration-count` in an invalid location, between keyframe blocks. `@keyframes` only accepts keyframe blocks, i.e. `?% {}` or `to/from {}`. You need to place it in the same selector as your `animation` property. Since you're using the shorthand `animation` property you can add an additional parameter to `animation` to signify the iteration count, `animation: sign-anim 3.5s 0.2s steps(85) forwards infinite;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ash06229/9ybp4zkp/

I changed your CSS little bit.

```
#dex-sign.play {
    -moz-animation: sign-anim 3.5s 0.2s steps(85) forwards;
    -o-animation: sign-anim 3.5s 0.2s steps(85) forwards;
    -webkit-animation: sign-anim 3.5s 0.2s steps(85) forwards;
    animation: sign-anim 3.5s 0.2s steps(85) forwards;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5000ms;
            animation-duration: 5000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes sign-anim {
    to {
        background-position: 0 -7140px;
    }
}
```